# Commenting results in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I'm using RStudio to write a report with R Markdown. I'm wondering if it is possible to knit a pdf chunk by chunk in order to add comments on the results I'm getting after each chunk. Since I'm using simulations and resampling the data changes every time.

Comment: use `set.seed()` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `set.seed()`, you may consider `opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = rand_seed)` in the setup chunk of `knitr`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ben noted, you should use `set.seed()` every time so that your random results aren't so random.

But to answer your question, you can run just one chunk at a time by selecting 'Run Current Chunk' from the 'Chunks' pulldown at top right.

[image]